# Is there "a rate of convergence" for the central limit theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. with zero mean and unit variance. Then according to the central limit theorem $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum \limits_{i=1}^n X_i \to_D \mathcal{N}(0,1),$$
as $n \to \infty$, where $\to_D$ denotes convergence in distribution. Can you say anything about the finite sample properties of the left hand side? Ideally, I would like to say in precise way that the distribution of the LHS is "almost" the RHS.

Comment: The rate is characterized by $\sqrt{n}$, whose precise meaning should be understood as in the definition of weak convergence. Empirically they say $n = 30$ might be a lower bound to get a decent approximation but this in fact heavily depends on the distribution of $X$. Anyway, I don't think your question should be considered as a mathematical question, you might get more desirable answers from crossvalidated stackexchange?

Comment: @Zhanxiong: Assume that LHS has a density $f_n$. What does "decent approximation" mean then? Something like $\sup \limits _{x \in \mathbb{R} } \left| f_n(x) - f(x) \right| < \varepsilon$, with $\varepsilon > 0$ and $f$ the density of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$? I understand that this might be a difficult question and the answer might heavily depend on the distribution of $X$. What I'm asking is, is there anything useful on these type of things?

Comment: Heikkila What you mentioned may probably be the results like Berry-Essen bound.

Comment: @Zhanxiong: Thanks Ill have a look at that!